# Moving text annotation to middle of arrowprop

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

Hi im generating an arrow prop using the code shown below:

```
axes.annotate('text', xy=(-1, -1), xytext=(-1, -1), xycoords='data', textcoords='data',
                  arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='<-', color='blue', linewidth=2))
```

This generates an arrow pointing away from text like the one shown:

[arrow generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1Yke.png)

I was wondering if it was possible to move the text so that the arrow itself was annotated like the one shown below:

[Arrow wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOdQn.png)

I'm going to generate some curved arrows so can't just use the halfway point between the start and end of the arrow.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Just leave out the animate part of the duplicate.